# What are examples of non thread-safe code in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I'm looking at using [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/), an asynchronous job processing queue written in Ruby which runs its jobs using threads.

Due to MRI and GIL, developers tend to stay away from writing multi-threaded code in Ruby and that's why there isn't a whole lot written about thread-safe code in Ruby.

Some common everyday patterns like `result ||= something.call` without a surrounding mutex is not thread safe. So my question is what are some other simple everyday Ruby code that's not thread safe?

Comment: I believe you should avoid storing data in class and global variables. So in general package data into instances and pass those around, rather than sharing variables through class methods.